# Cannot start mule with spring and java 7

Tags: java, spring, mule

I am new in development with mule, i am using java 7 to develop an application that uses mule.

The problem is that i am not able to start mule, i am not sure but looking to the logs, i think that there is a problem with my spring configuration and mule.

in the log there is a code error: MULE_ERROR-71999 !!!.

here is the log:

```
INFO  2020-11-20 15:03:20,721 [main] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Overriding bean definition for bean 'manual-fix-file-injection': replacing [Root bean: class [org.mule.construct.Flow]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=initialise; destroyMethodName=dispose] with [Root bean: class [org.mule.construct.Flow]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=initialise; destroyMethodName=dispose]
INFO  2020-11-20 15:03:20,723 [main] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Overriding bean definition for bean 'manual-fix-file-injection': replacing [Root bean: class [org.mule.construct.Flow]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=initialise; destroyMethodName=dispose] with [Root bean: class [org.mule.construct.Flow]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=initialise; destroyMethodName=dispose]
INFO  2020-11-20 15:03:20,727 [main] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Overriding bean definition for bean 'async-save-fill': replacing [Root bean: class [org.mule.construct.Flow]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=initialise; destroyMethodName=dispose] with [Root bean: class [org.mule.construct.Flow]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=initialise; destroyMethodName=dispose]
ERROR 2020-11-20 15:03:21,227 [main] org.mule.MuleServer: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : null
Type                  : org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException
Code                  : MULE_ERROR-71999
JavaDoc               : http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/lifecycle/InitialisationException.html
Object                : org.mule.config.spring.SpringRegistry@47e706fd
********************************************************************************
Exception stack is:
1. null (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException)
  org.springframework.asm.ClassReader:-1 (null)
2. null (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException)
  org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry:117 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/lifecycle/InitialisationException.html)
********************************************************************************
Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:52)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:80)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:102)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:76)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassUtils.checkConfigurationClassCandidate(ConfigurationClassUtils.java:70)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:253)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:223)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:630)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringRegistry.doInitialise(SpringRegistry.java:89)
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:109)
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.createSpringRegistry(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:119)
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:73)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:46)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:78)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.autoConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:101)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:57)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:46)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:78)
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:84)
    at org.mule.MuleServer.initialize(MuleServer.java:383)
    at org.mule.MuleServer.run(MuleServer.java:292)
    at org.mule.MuleServer.start(MuleServer.java:279)
    at com.vmd.mule.MuleServerWrapper.main(MuleServerWrapper.java:36)

********************************************************************************

ERROR 2020-11-20 15:03:21,231 [main] org.mule.MuleServer: 
********************************************************************************
* A Fatal error has occurred while the server was running:                     *
* null (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException)                                    *
*                                                                              *
* The error is fatal, the system will shutdown                                 *
********************************************************************************
INFO  2020-11-20 15:03:21,232 [Thread-0] com.vmd.mule.MuleServerWrapper: Shutting down Mule
INFO  2020-11-20 15:03:21,232 [Thread-0] com.vmd.mule.MuleServerWrapper: Mule is DOWN
```

I tried also to run mule under jre 1.8, and when I do it I get the following error:

```
JDK Version 1.8.0_241 and/or Vendor Oracle Corporation are not supported. Please use a supported version: [1.6.0,1.7),[1.7.0,1.8).
```

Any help or suggestion would be very appreciated.

Comment: Java 7 is really old. What version of Mule are you trying to use? Something equally old? The current version (4.3) requires Java 8 or 11.

Comment: i  am using mule 3.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was caused by a dependency jar that was created with java 8, I had to recompile the project and the dependencies with java 7 to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Are really sure Java 7 is used to start Mule 3.4? Probably that version is not compatible with Java 8 and that can cause this error. If you are using Anypoint Studio, or the older Mule Studio, be sure that the execution environment is pointing to a Java 7 SDK.

If you are using the command line you need to check that wrapper.conf points to the right java executable for Java 7 (example `wrapper.java.command=/path/to/jdk7/bin/java`).

3.4 is absolutely end of life and ancient, same as Java 7. I recommend to migrate to current versions as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is to upgrade to at least OpenJDK 8, if not 11. Java 7 is very old now and gets absolutely no free security updates anymore. Using it for new development is tantamount to building security holes into your system.

Comment: I tried to do this to run under jre 1.8, I get the error you can see in my question (edited)

Comment: It's telling you to stop using an Oracle version of the JDK. You need to switch to OpenJDK instead, like one of the ones available from adoptopenjdk.net

Comment: We're at version 1.8u272 or something like that now; u241 is probably a good 1.5-2 years old.